# scroll based pagination fetching not working in supabase using range(from, to)

Tags: react-hooks, infinite-scroll, next.js13, supabase, intersection-observer

i'm trying to leverage infinite scrolling by increasing the number of posts in the array of post by fetching more as the user scrolls towards the end of the page, i have the arguments for the parameters in the range(from , to) defined , which are to increase on every additional fetch, so as to keep fetching more data with respect to the range being passed. these arguments increase when i log them to the console but they dont seem to increase within the fetch function

i tried  this

```js
"use client";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import supabase from "@/lib/supabaseClient";
import PostCard from "../home/PostCard";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";

interface PostCardProps {
   author: string;
   id: string;
   image: string;
   snippet: string;
   author_verification: boolean;
   title: string;
   created_at: string;
   category_name: string;
   author_image: string;
   bookmark_count: number;
   likes_count: number;
   comment_count: number;
   profile_id: string;
}

const PAGE_COUNT = 5;
export default function TicketsPage() {
   const [posts, setPosts] = useState<PostCardProps[]>([]);
   const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
   const [error, setError] = useState<string | null>(null);
   const [nextPage, setNextPage] = useState(1);
   const [NUM_TO_FETCH, setNUM_TO_FETCH] = useState(1);
   const [isFetching, setIsFetching] = useState(false);

   useEffect(() => {
      const fetchInitialPosts = async () => {
         try {
            const { data, error } = await supabase
               .from("posts")
               .select("*")
               .range(0, PAGE_COUNT - 1)
               .order("created_at", { ascending: false });

            if (!error && data) {
               setPosts(data);
            } else {
               setError("An error occurred while fetching posts.");
            }
         } catch (error) {
            setError("An error occurred while fetching posts.");
         }
      };

      fetchInitialPosts();
   }, []);

   // Fetch more posts
   const fetchMorePosts = async () => {
      if (isFetching) {
         return; // If already fetching, do nothing
      }

      setIsFetching(true);

      try {
         const from = nextPage * PAGE_COUNT; // Calculate the offset
         const to = from + PAGE_COUNT - 1;
         const { data, error } = await supabase
            .from("posts")
            .select("*")
            .range(from, to)
            .order("created_at", { ascending: true });

         if (!error) {
            if (data && data.length > 0) {
               setPosts((prevPosts) => [...prevPosts, ...data]);
               setNextPage((prev) => prev + 1);

               console.log("fetching from :", from);
               console.log("to", to);
               console.log(from);
            } else {
               setError("No more posts to fetch.");
            }
         } else {
            setError("An error occurred while fetching more posts.");
         }
      } catch (error) {
         setError("An error occurred while fetching more posts.");
      } finally {
         setIsFetching(false); // Set isFetching to false after fetching is complete
      }
   };

   // Load more posts when reaching the bottom
   useEffect(() => {
      const handleScroll = () => {
         if (
            window.innerHeight + document.documentElement.scrollTop ===
            document.documentElement.offsetHeight
         ) {
            fetchMorePosts();
         }
      };

      window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);

      return () => {
         window.removeEventListener("scroll", handleScroll);
      };
   }, []);

   return (
      <>
         <div className="flex flex-col w-full gap-5 px-6 pt-10">
            {posts.map((post, index) => (
               <motion.div
                  key={post.id}
                  initial={{ opacity: 0, y: 20 }}
                  animate={{ opacity: 1, y: 0 }}
                  transition={{
                     duration: 0.4,
                     ease: [0.25, 0.25, 0, 1],
                     delay: index / 15, // Adjust the delay as needed
                  }}>
                  <>
                     <div>{index}</div>
                     <PostCard {...post} />
                  </>
               </motion.div>
            ))}

            {isLoading && <div>Loading...</div>}
            {error && <div>Error: {error}</div>}
         </div>
      </>
   );
}
```

and i was expecting the function to load more posts as the arguments state changes but it keeps rendering the same thing over and over

Comment: Do you want to console log the `nextPage` variable and see if it's being incremented everytime you make a request?

Comment: yeah i have already done that and thats how i noticed the variable to increase the range isnt increasing and thats why i keep getting the same posts rendered

Comment: So every single time you console log `nextPage`, it's `1`? Do you want to try `setNextPage(nextPage + 1);`?

Comment: hmm i will try that now.